# Single switch with 2 lights, not in series

Tags: electrical

The 1st image below is a typical diagram for a switch with 2 lights. I have a scenario where I can't wire the 2 lights in series because they go off in different directions. Can I wire it like the 2nd (modified) image below?

[image]

[image]

Comment: We wire lights in parallel not in series. You can tap the conductors at the existing light or the switch location.

Comment: Neither of these is series. Be aware that in many cases power does not come as illustrated, conveniently into the switch box first from a different direction than the lights.

Comment: This is a step up from the usual MS Paint drawings. It looks like you cut apart the first image and reassembled it in Photoshop or another image editor.

Comment: The first image shows the lights electrically in parallel even though the cable is going in series to each light.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I the simplest of terms. Yes you can.

Comment: Thanks. Previously, there were 2 sets of wires running from the box to one of the lights. I am assuming one going to the light, and one going back to the same box, where I assume it connected to the other light. Is there a preferred method? I would assume running just one wire is easier.

Comment: No, that was probably **power** coming from the light fixture location to the switch, and **switched power** going back to the light(s).

Comment: One line winning answer. Also a win for OP since they did their homework.

Comment: There are 2 romex cables running from the switch to one light fixture and they are not live. That is what confused me. It sounds like I can wire it like I show in the 2nd image and just remove one of the wires. Thanks!